# Efficient way to print large data.frame with kable

Tags: r, knitr, kable, kableextra

I want to print a large `data.frame` with `kable`. I divided the data.frame into parts. Is there a more efficient method with less code?

```
mt1 <-
  matrix(
    data = runif(n = 200, min = 101, max = 999)
  , nrow = 10
  , ncol = 20
  , byrow = TRUE
  , dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:10], paste0("V", 1:20))
  )

df1 <- data.frame(Name = row.names(mt1), mt1) 

library(kableExtra)

kable(df1[,c(1, 2:6)], format = "rst", row.names = FALSE)
kable(df1[,c(1, 7:11)], format = "rst", row.names = FALSE)
kable(df1[,c(1, 12:16)], format = "rst", row.names = FALSE)
kable(df1[,c(1, 17:21)], format = "rst", row.names = FALSE)
```

**Edited**

```
library(tidyverse)
kable(df1[,c(1, 2:6)], format = "latex", row.names = FALSE) %>% 
  row_spec(row = c(0), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE, align = "l")

kable(df1[,c(1, 7:11)], format = "latex", row.names = FALSE) %>% 
  row_spec(row = c(0), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE, align = "l")

kable(df1[,c(1, 12:16)], format = "latex", row.names = FALSE) %>% 
  row_spec(row = c(0), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE, align = "l")

kable(df1[,c(1, 17:21)], format = "latex", row.names = FALSE) %>% 
  row_spec(row = c(0), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE, align = "l")
```

Comment: It is not clear which way you want to apply the `kable`. Do you need a `for` loop? i.e.`f1 <- function(dat, i1, i2) {kable(dat[, c(1, i1:i2)], format = "latex", row.names = FALSE) %>% row_spec(row = c(0), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE, align = "l")}; v1 <- seq(2, 17, by = 5); v2 <- seq(6, 21, by = 5); for(i in seq_along(v1) print(f1(df1, v1[i], v2[i]))`

Comment: Gentle reminder: how much you would appreciate assistance, how much you need help, how stuck you are, how long this bug has been troubling you, and all other forms of implicit pleading, are best left out of your posts. Please try to stick to technical writing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the index and pass it to `Map`

```
Map(function(i, j) kable(df1[c(1, i:j)], format = 'rst', 
        row.names = FALSE), seq(2, 17, by = 5), seq(6, 21, by = 5))
```

---

Or use `split` with a grouping index created with `gl`

```
lapply(split.default(df1[, -1], as.integer(gl(ncol(df1)-1,  5,
  ncol(df1) - 1))), function(x) 
         kable(cbind(df1[1], x), format = 'rst', row.names = FALSE))
#$`1`


#====  ========  ========  ========  ========  ========
#Name        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
#====  ========  ========  ========  ========  ========
#A     359.0833  809.0627  150.5985  651.3763  200.7702
#B     338.8996  388.5825  612.0037  695.4628  709.0798
#C     760.0153  423.7709  956.7838  799.0494  663.9588
#D     319.5298  683.4278  144.7564  757.8725  694.7529
#E     294.5364  954.1390  223.0555  227.9699  347.4535
#F     117.1561  281.8261  205.4815  265.4050  227.5070
#G     944.5761  312.9263  741.1121  533.0935  833.5107
#H     145.8520  223.1062  802.7357  570.6363  871.7380
#I     591.0673  490.9409  722.8031  307.7193  226.9439
#J     152.7567  756.3408  970.0148  941.1165  125.0778
#====  ========  ========  ========  ========  ========

#$`2`
#...
```

With the edits, it would be

```
lapply(split.default(df1[, -1], as.integer(gl(ncol(df1)-1,  5,
  ncol(df1) - 1))), function(x) 
         kable(cbind(df1[1], x), format = 'latex', row.names = FALSE) %>% 
             row_spec(row = c(0), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE, align = "l"))
```

---

If we want to add a pagebreak

```
f1 <- function(dat, i1, i2) {
     kable(dat[, c(1, i1:i2)], format = "latex", row.names = FALSE) %>% 
         row_spec(row = c(0), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE, align = "l")}

v1 <- seq(2, 17, by = 5)
v2 <- seq(6, 21, by = 5)
for(i in seq_along(v1) {
    print(f1(df1, v1[i], v2[i]))
    if(i < length(v1)) {
     cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for your answer. However I'm facing difficulty to use it with kableextra for latex. Please see my edits.

Comment: The latex output have the names of lists which is not required. Would appreciate if you guide to how to each out put table in new page. thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 just do `unname(split.default(df1[, -1], as.integer(gl(ncol(df1)-1,  5,
  ncol(df1) - 1))))`

Comment: Even `unname()` gives some extra output.

Comment: The code `lapply(unname(split.default(df1[, -1], as.integer(gl(ncol(df1)-1,  5,
                                              ncol(df1) - 1)))), function(x) 
                                                kable(cbind(df1[1], x), format = 'latex', row.names = FALSE) %>% 
         row_spec(row = c(0), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE, align = "l"))` works fine except two problems. It also also print `[[1]], [[2]], [[3]], [[4]]` which is not required. I also want next table on new page. Any thoughts. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 You can add a conditional statement with `if`. can you try the update